# Finder not showing all folders of home folder

Tags: macos, finder

In a terminal, `ls -al`, lists the complete folder contents of the home folder. Among the folders, there are Downloads and Documents. Both have the exact same access rights set.

Now when I open the home folder in Finder. The Documents folder is missing. Why?

[image: Screenshot of the Home folder showing the Applications and Downloads folder but no Documents folder]

The output of `ls -al` for the home folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x@  3 christian  staff   96B Dec 19 14:17 Applications
drwx------@  4 christian  staff  128B Dec 21 09:57 Desktop
drwx------@  8 christian  staff  256B Dec 21 09:57 Documents
drwx------@  8 christian  staff  256B Dec 21 10:01 Downloads
```

Comment: Does `ls -lOd ~/Documents` show a hidden flag? If so try `chflags nohidden ~/Documents`.

Comment: Do you have iCloud switched on? If so, then Documents and Desktop (also missing in your screenshots) will be in a separate grouping in Finder. You could look and see if enabled in the Finder settings | Sidebar (this may also be why they're missing even if you don't use iCloud, but I can't double check at the moment...). Also, check your iCloud Drive sync settings, as there's a specific Desktop & Documents option there that determines if they sync.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: there is no hidden flag

Comment: @AndyGriffiths: iCloud is switched on. Either way, I want to see the content of the folder when I have it open - period. I feel like any OS should have that option readily available. If it doesn't, then that OS is obviously not designed for power users / developers etc. (sorry, bit frustrated with the many shortcomings of OSX)

Comment: You are being unnecessarily frustrated, though most power users would argue the weapon of choice is the command line, not UI ;-) See my answer.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths: being a power user is about capabilities as well as being quick. While the terminal is an indispensable tool for any power user it is not always the fasted way to access files via favorites etc.

Answer (score 0):

The folders are hidden by default (and design) when viewing the contents of your user folder in Finder, and by mechanisms other than the standard flags, (possibly when iCloud is enabled, but I can't test at present, and discussions as to Apple's motives are OT).

If you use `ls -l@ad ~/Documents` in Terminal, however you will see iCloud specific extended attributes that no-doubt instruct Finder to perform some special behaviour for the Folder to hide it. There will be a comparable structure in `~/Library` also which enables the iCloud replication to work. Of course, this applies to `~/Desktop` also. That is the limit of my knowledge unfortunately.

```
% ls -l@ad ~/Documents
drwx------@ 268 USER  staff  8576 11 Jan 14:59 /Users/USER/Documents
    com.apple.icloud.desktop       9 
    com.apple.macl    72 
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags   42
```

However, the hidden folders can be shown in Finder using `Cmd-Shift-Period`. This also reveals all the other hidden folders that other software uses to store settings, caches etc...

To show the iCloud folders in the Finder sidebar, enable in the Finder settings | Sidebar.