# Folder structure in finder different than terminal (and different from expected). Not hidden dirs

Tags: finder

If I open Finder on my Mac, under settings I have it set to open at my home directory. From there I see Downloads, Music, Movies, Pictures etc directories. I don't see Documents though.

If I `command + shift + .` to see hidden files and folders, I still do not see Documents.

In the terminal if I type `ls -l ~` I see the directories listed above AND Documents.

Whats happening here? How can I navigate finder using the directory structure?

[image]
[image]

[edit]
Adding output of `ls -le@Od ~/Documents` per comment
[image]

Comment: Can you show output of `ls -le@Od ~/Documents`? If it has the hidden flag, do `chflags nohidden ~/Documents`.

Comment: Hi @Gilby screen shot of `ls -le@Od ~/Documents` added now. I don't see anything about hidden flags at first glance but am less familiar with this command. Does the screen provide any helpful info?

Comment: Documents and Desktop are under iCloud in the sidebar.  There should be links to the folders on iCloud Drive though in your home directory.

Comment: @Redarm If I remove them from icloud they still don't appear. I want to be able to access these dirs using regular drill down, not via icloud sidebar

Comment: When you "remove them from icloud", do you toggle the setting? Maybe try toggling again, followed by a reboot? https://support.apple.com/HT206985#:~:text=Turn%20off%20Desktop%20and%20Documents

Comment: Also, **please copy/paste Terminal output as text and format as code**. This makes it much easier to read for everybody and is essential for vision-impaired users.

Comment: Looks like `Documents` is in iCloud, or used to be in the past and resetting it back to local went wrong. Is there a Documents folder in iCloud, with your current content?

Comment: Just a thought: if you try to open Desktop, or Documents from Terminal in Finder, does that change/do anything?

Comment: Thanks for the link @Redarm, this solved my problem "If you turn off iCloud Drive or sign out of iCloud, a new Desktop and Documents folder will be created in your home folder. ". Should I c lose/delete this post?

Comment: Please post your findings/solution as an answer, others may run into similar issues in the future and benefit from your analysis.

Comment: It might also be a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452224/finder-not-showing-all-folders-of-home-folder?rq=1, actually

Comment: @DougFir As you wrote, it was just a comment with tools/info for you to solve your issue. Go on and post the answer - you know best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I was syncing Documents with icloud. After removing this sync ~/Documents appeared for me again in finder. [Info in link in the comments](https://support.apple.com/HT206985#:%7E:text=Turn%20off%20Desktop%20and%20Documents).

> What happens when you turn off iCloud Drive or sign out of iCloud?
>
> If you turn off iCloud Drive or sign out of iCloud, a new Desktop and
> Documents folder will be created in your home folder. You also have
> the option to keep a local copy of your files that are in iCloud
> Drive. If you keep a local copy of your files that are in iCloud
> Drive, they will be copied to a folder called iCloud Drive (Archive)
> in your home folder. You can move any files that were in your iCloud
> Desktop and Documents to your new local Desktop and Documents.

Comment: Just to clarify: did you also (firstly) try and specifically only turn off Desktop & Documents in iCloud and it didn't recreate the local folders (i.e. the paragraph before the quoted one)?

Comment: @Redarm no, I switched icloud off entirely. I'm unsure of the outcome of the above. In my case I don't need it